# Can a 10K+ help copy an answer to Math.SE?

Tags: support, specific-question

[A question was posted on Math.SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/592416/1543) late last year, which I [noted is very similar to a question posted here on MO](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/592416/reference-request-trace-integral-formula?noredirect=1#comment1252144_592416). The author seemed to have been somewhat satisfied with the answer given on MO. But the MO question was closed as off-topic and now, deleted.

If it is not too much trouble, can someone with enough privilege to see [this deleted question here](https://mathoverflow.net/a/150260/3948) either copy the answer over to Math.SE, or perhaps post a copy of the answer below so I can copy it to Math.SE? I would also be grateful if a link to the user who posted the original answer is given so proper credit can be given.

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I undeleted and reopened, with the idea to reclose to migrate to MSE, which would have the action of moving Bennett Chow's answer with it. However, for some reason I don't understand, when I try to close to migrate, that option is not popping up for me. Strange.

I'm going to reclose now, and see if we can figure out what's going on. Bear with us.

Comment: Questions older than 30 days cannot be migrated, not even by mods.

Comment: I've cp'd Ben Chow's answer to MSE as a CW. Thanks for making it (at least temporarily) visible.

Comment: Thanks, Willie. Still learning here.